# Service error: SitesApp: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

When I try to delete some pages from a Google Site I have this error :

*Service error: SitesApp: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.(line 3)*

Script:

```
function deletePages() {
var announcementpage = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('url'); 
var announcements = announcementpage.getAllDescendants(); 

for (var i=0; i<announcements.length; i++){
announcements[i].deletePage();
}
announcementpage.deletePage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should report this error in issue tracker as this doesn't seem the bug with Apps Script.
[Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry)